# Getting a specific version of an image with Jib (Maven, Docker, testcontainers)

Tags: java, docker, maven, testcontainers, jib

I'm trying to understand a comment that a colleague made. We're using [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) to create a fixture:

```
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

public class SalesforceFixture extends GenericContainer<SalesforceFixture> {

  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "salesforce-emulator";

  public SalesforceFixture() {
    // super(ImageResolver.resolve(APPLICATION_NAME));
    super(DockerImageName.parse("gcr.io/ad-selfserve/salesforce-emulator:latest"));
    ...
  }

...
```

The commented code is what it used to be. The next line is my colleague's suggestion. And on that line he commented:

> This is the part I don't know. The [ImageResolver] gets the specific version of the emulator, rather than the latest. You need a docker-info file for that though, which jib doesn't automatically generate (but I think it can).

This is what I know or have figured so far:

1. SalesforceFixture is a class that will be used by other projects to write tests. It spins up a container in Docker, running a service that emulates the real service's API. It's like a local version of the service that behaves *enough* like the real thing that if one writes code and tests  using the fixture, it *should* work the same in production. (This is where my knowledge ends.)
2. I looked into `ImageResolver`—it seems to be a class we wrote that searches a filesystem for something:

   ```
     public static String resolve(String applicationName, File... roots) {
       Stream<File> searchPaths = Arrays.stream(roots).flatMap((value) -> {
         return Stream.of(new File(value, "../" + applicationName), new File(value, applicationName));
       });
       Optional<File> buildFile = searchPaths.flatMap((searchFile) -> {
         if (searchFile.exists()) {
           File imageFile = new File(searchFile + File.separator + "/target/docker/image-name");
           if (imageFile.exists()) {
             return Stream.of(imageFile);
           }
         }

         return Stream.empty();
       }).findAny();
       InputStream build = (InputStream)buildFile.map(ImageResolver::fileStream).orElseGet(() -> {
         return searchClasspath(applicationName);
       });
       if (build != null) {
         try {
           return IOUtils.toString(build, Charset.defaultCharset()).trim();
         } catch (IOException var6) {
           throw new RuntimeException("An exception has occurred while reading build file", var6);
         }
       } else {
         throw new RuntimeException("Could not resolve target image for application: " + applicationName);
       }
     }
   ```

   But I'm confused. What filesystem? Like, what is the present working directory? My local computer, wherever I ran the Java program from? Or is this from within some container? (I don't think so.) Or maybe the directory structure inside a .jar file? Or somewhere in gcr.io?
3. What does he mean about a "specific version number" vs. "latest"? I mean, when I build this project, whatever it built is all I have. Isn't that equivalent to "latest"? In what case would an older version of an image be present? (That's what made me think of gcr.io.)
4. Or, does he mean, that *in the project using this project's image*, one will not be able to specify a version via Maven/pom.xml—it will always spin up the latest.

Sorry this is long, just trying to "show my work." Any hints welcome. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Edited. It may not be the right question still—I don't know enough to know what I'm looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on specifics of your own internal implementations, but `ImageResolver` seems to work on your local filesystem, e.g. it looks into your `target/` directory and also touches the classpath. I can imagine this code was just written for resolving an actual image name (not an image), since it also returns a `String`.

Regarding `latest`, using a `latest` tag for a Docker image is generally considered an anti-pattern, so likely your colleague is commenting about this. Here is a random article from the web explaining some of the issues with `latest` tag:
https://vsupalov.com/docker-latest-tag/

Besides, I don't understand why you ask these questions which are very specific to your project here on SO rather than asking your colleague.